# Bug in Application Registration Portal for v2 app model

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I found an annoying little bug in the Application Registration Portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList):

Whenever I update some things (like a redirect URI) the value of the privacy URL will be gone.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create application
- Enter Privacy URL
- Save
- Change Redirect URI
- Save
- Privacy URL is gone now!!

Is this a known bug ? Could you please fix this.

Comment: Thanks! Looking into it.